# Laravel 5 Can't Use User Class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller

I'm new to Laravel. I just installed Laravel 5 and have been going through some video tutorials in order to learn how it works.

I want to use the User class as it seems like it is very useful. In my web.php (routes) file, I have:

```
use app\Models\User;      

Route::get('/users', function (){
        $users = User::all(); //select * from users
        return $users;
      });
```

I get the following error upon loading that route in my browser:

[image]

I have a User.php file placed in my app/Models/ directory, and also changed in my auth.php file for it to reference this.

There are countless questions like this online and I try the fixes but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: is you app still called `app` or did you change it using `php artisan app:name <name>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Models` from use statement. It's not directory... Model is in namespace `App` so use:

```
use App\User;
```

Namespace and Directory is completely different things...

Or if you want to use in directory `app/Models` go to `User.php` model file and change namespace from `App` to `App\Models`

Comment: I had this originally, and it didn't work. Just changed it back now, and no dice.

Comment: Can you paste your User model content? and which is Line 10 on your route file?

Comment: I believe I just fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, because it's namespace is `App` and directory is `app`